# How to open the send message window without username

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

In the case of having a username, I can use the following two links:

1. https://t.me/username
2. tg://resolve?domain=username

What if I don't have a username, only the user ID? Some users did not set a username.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
[$name](tg://user?id=$id)
```